# Drop down menu gives PY_VAR0 in txt file

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a little project for my friends and it's with python tkinter.

the code is

```
def run():
    filename = filename_ent.get()
    if filename == '':
        # to show an error that boxes are empty
        messagebox.showerror(
            'File exists', 'File already exists, try some other name thas is not used before')
    if os.path.exists(f'{filename}.txt'):
        # to show an error if the file already exists
        messagebox.showerror(
            'File exists', 'File already exists, try some other name not used before')
    else:
        # to open the file for python
        new = open(f'{filename}.txt', '+w', encoding='utf-8')
        # to write the name and email inside the file
        new.write(f'''Day of the week: {clicked}''')
        eventl.config(text=f'Done :)!')  # to change the label to the name
        os.startfile(f'{filename}.txt')  # to open the file in a new window




eventl = Label(root, text='What is the name of the event',font=('helvatica',14))
eventl.place(x=0,y=0)

lfilename = Label(root,text="What do you want to call the file?", font = ("helvatica, 14"))
lfilename.pack()
filename_ent = Entry(root)
filename_ent.pack(pady=10,padx=30)
clicked = StringVar()
drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, "Monday", "Tuesday")        
drop.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
b = Button(root, text='Done', command=run)
b.pack(pady=(10, 0))
root.mainloop()
```

**Note:** I'm using utf-8 because I'm also using Arabic inputs but that doesn't seem to be the problem since I tried removing it(this isn't the whole code).

Comment: `new.write(f'Day of the week: {clicked.get()}')` will do it.

Comment: No, I'm getting another error when choosing the options
Thanks for the try tho <3
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'

Comment: @Mr_Oliver Where are you using `set()`, it should be `get()`, either way such an error shouldnt be shown, can you edit the Q with the complete error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `new.write(f'''Day of the week: {clicked.get()}''')` instead of `new.write(f'''Day of the week: {clicked}''')`. Clicked is the just the `StringVar()` you have to access the value of it using the `get()` method.

Hope this helped, do let me know if any errors.

Cheers